# SQL query to return records from one table that are associated to 2 records each from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

1. Orders

```
+------------+
| Orders IDs |
+------------+
|      11462 |
|      25014 |
|      40328 |
+------------+
```

2. Changes

```
+------------+------------+------------------+
| Orders IDs | Change IDs | Change Status    |
+------------+------------+------------------+
|      86351 |      18762 | archived         |
|      47622 |      19129 | pending_approval |
|      11462 |       3089 | draft            |
|      11462 |       3122 | draft            |
|      25014 |       6339 | draft            |
|      25014 |       6465 | draft            |
|      40328 |      14677 | draft            |
|      40328 |      14678 | draft            |
|      89901 |      19577 | approved         |
|      88413 |      19578 | pending_approval |
+------------+------------+------------------+
```

How do I query so that I am given a table containing order IDs that are associated to 2 changes that are in draft status? What query (ran against the table above) will return:

```
+------------+------------+---------------+
| Orders IDs | Change IDs | Change Status |
+------------+------------+---------------+
|      11462 |       3089 | draft         |
|      11462 |       3122 | draft         |
|      25014 |       6339 | draft         |
|      25014 |       6465 | draft         |
|      40328 |      14677 | draft         |
|      40328 |      14678 | draft         |
+------------+------------+---------------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, count(*) over (partition by order_id, change_status) as cnt
      from drafts d
      where change_status = 'draft'
     ) d
where cnt = 2;
```

This can easily be modified if you really intend "2 or more".

Or, assuming that `change_id` is unique and you want 2 or more, use `exists`:

```
select d.*
from drafts d
where d.change_status = 'draft' and
      exists (select 1
              from drafts d2
              where d2.order_id = d.order_id and 
                    d2.change_status = 'draft' and
                    d2.change_id <> d.change_id
             );
```

Comment: Thank you ! the second query worked like a charm:
select ohc.id, ohc.status, ohc.order_header_id, ohc.created_at, ohc.created_by_id from order_header_changes ohc where ohc.status = 'draft' and exists (select 1 from order_header_changes ohc2 where ohc2.order_header_id = ohc.order_header_id and ohc2.status = 'draft' and ohc2.id <> ohc.id);

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is it you exactly need you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM changes
where Change_Status = 'draft'
order by Orders_IDs;
```

or like this:

```
select c.* 
from orders o
left join changes c
on o.Orders_IDs = c.Orders_IDs
where c.Change_Status = 'draft'
order by c.Orders_IDs;
```

[here is a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d6c23/7)